Why is Linux in ChromeOS Flex reporting wrong number of CPU sockets?
dajnyx@penguin:~$ lscpu 
...
CPU(s):                   2
  On-line CPU(s) list:    0,1
Vendor ID:                GenuineIntel
  Model name:             Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU 1037U @ 1.80GHz
    CPU family:           6
    Model:                58
    Thread(s) per core:   1
    Core(s) per socket:   1
    Socket(s):            2
...

It should be sockets 1 and cores per socket 2. It is the same problem with other CPUs I have tested. This causes some programs to misbehave.
This is ChromeOS Flex version 126.0.6478.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)
The distribution is (in /etc/debian_version):
Debian 12.6
The kernel is (according to uname -a):
Linux penguin 6.6.30-02725-g3e8c91b46252 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri, 21 Jun 2024 04:09:40 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux

This isn't Linux reporting that, it's lscpu. I'd invite you to ask a new question actually describing the problems and asking for help with them – you're probably the wrong lead here.
Anyways, lscpu calculates the numbers of sockets as number of cores you have, divided by the number of siblings per core, https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/master/sys-utils/lscpu-topology.c . It gets these numbers from sysfs, specifically /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu{0,1}/topology/core_siblings_list (or, more modern, …/package_cpus_list).
If I remember this correctly, that information is actually read during boot from the CPU itself (Linux kernel smpboot.c in arch/x86). Why intel or your vendor-modified microcode image decided to fill that in incorrectly? Can't tell. Possibly, it's correct to think of that CPU as two single-core CPUs in separate sockets; according to wikipedia, they don't share L2 caches, and since they're pretty old, mitigation against speculative-execution data leakage vulnerabilities might suggest it's a good idea to scrub tables before migrating a task to another core. I honestly don't know.
I also really really wonder what problems that would cause in an old Chromebook!
